# Azure Data Studio - Detach Results Window

Tags: azure-data-studio

Is it possible to detach the Results Window, in Azure Data Studio? I have multiple monitors and I want to use them on this program as well :)
I know Windows+Shift+R shows/hide the window, what I need is to detach it (Floating Window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Meanwhile you can open multiple windows by clicking `Ctrl + Shift + N` or from the `File` menu, but I assume that is not the desired functionality.

There is an issue raised for this feature in VS Code repository https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10121 and it is still in the backlog.

(I assume you know, and this is just a reminder. Azure Data Studio is related to VS code. So when it comes to VS Code, it will eventually be supported in ADS.)

Answer (score 0):

just press Shift+Windows+R.
It works for me.

Comment: I know about Shift + Win + R, but that only shows/hides the window. I was asking about moving the window to another monitor (detach).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).